# Hive transform using python return map<string,string> type

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I would like to do an insert with a transformation from a source table to a destination table without dumping contents or creating new tables, views etc. 
So I started thinking about streaming the content from the original table, modifying it on the fly and write to the destination table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE d SELECT TRANSFORM item USING 'python po.py' AS (item map<string,string>) FROM s;
```

where d is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE d (item map<string, string>)
```

and s is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE s (item map<string, string>)
```

What should I print from the python script to properly get data transformed and loaded into table d?

I tried to print different representations from the python script but it seems that the generated item will always result in a wrong format:

Something like this:

`{"item":{"representation":null}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a string in a specific format and cast it to map using **str_to_map**.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

#### Demo

**bash**

```
cat>/tmp/myscript.sh
sed -r -e 's/\{(.*)\}/\1/' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/v(.)/v\100/g'
```

**hive**

```
create table d (item map<string,string>);
create table s (item map<string,string>);
insert into s select map('k1','v1','k2','v2','k3','v3');
```

---

```
add file /tmp/myscript.sh;
```

---

```
insert into d

select  str_to_map (result)

from   (select  transform (item) using "myscript.sh" as result
        from    s
        ) t
;
```

---

```
select * from d
;
```

---

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                d.item                 |
+---------------------------------------+
| {"k1":"v100","k2":"v200","k3":"v300"} |
+---------------------------------------+
```

... and for some clarity:

```
select * from s;
```

---

```
+---------------------------------+
|             s.item              |
+---------------------------------+
| {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3"} |
+---------------------------------+
```

---

```
select  result
       ,str_to_map (result)  result_to_map

from   (select  transform (item) using "myscript.sh" as result
               
        from    s
        ) t
;
```

---

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|         result          |              result_map               |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| k1:v100,k2:v200,k3:v300 | {"k1":"v100","k2":"v200","k3":"v300"} |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

---

```
hive> explain
    > select  str_to_map (result)
    > 
    > from   (select  transform (item) using "myscript.sh" as result
    >         from    s
    >         ) t
    > ;
OK
Explain
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: s
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 17 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: item (type: map<string,string>)
              outputColumnNames: _col0
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 17 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Transform Operator
                command: myscript.sh
                output info:
                    input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                    output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                    serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 17 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: str_to_map(_col0) (type: map<string,string>)
                  outputColumnNames: _col0
                  Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 17 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 17 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        ListSink
```

Comment: Hi Dudu, thanks for the answer but how would you apply the str_to_map using the stream functionality "transform using"?

Comment: It is still a SELECT, so you can use it on the returned column.  If you won't manage I'll show you an example when I'll return home

Comment: Ok Dudu, I edited the question so it could be more appropriate

Comment: Hi Dudu, thanks again. My only concern is the same as before: what if s is 10 TB? Do you think that your solution with 't' would work?

Comment: Nested queries does not necessarily mean additional steps. If you'll take a look on the execution plan (added to my answer) you'll see that it's all takes place in a single MAP stage.

Comment: Perfect Dudu. I used the same approach but thought it would have been not doable with big data load, so I was looking for something different. I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dudu, is your student here XD... Just to ask to you one different thing. In the case I would like to write to two different tables with two different transform from the same table, which is your suggestion? So in the example below suppose you have two scripts that have to transform each item of the same table 's' to two tables (possibly using just one iteration of s)

Comment: Hi @Momo - I don't see any reason why not doing it as two separated CTAS / INSERT operations. If you think I'm missing something - please open a new post.

Comment: Just to avoid waiting for two scans in case of huge data loads (assuming the two loads are done sequentially).